# memory leaked when globaly declared?

Tags: c++, valgrind

Is this code still going to leak if instead of declaring the pointers as part of main I declare them globally? 
I tested with Valgrind memcheck and it doesn't

```
class Test1 {
public:
   Test1() { std::cout << "Constructor of Test " << std::endl; }
  ~Test1() { std::cout << "Destructor of Test "  << std::endl; }
};

    //Memory leaked or not when globally declared?
    // Test1 *t1;
    // Test1 *t2;
    // Test1 *t;

int main()
{
    //mem will leak if not deallocated later
    Test1 *t1;
    Test1 *t2;
    Test1 *t;

  try {

    t1=new Test1[100];

    t2=new Test1;
    t =new Test1;

    throw 10;
  }
  catch(int i)
    {
        std::cout << "Caught " << i << std::endl;

        // delete []t1;
        // delete t;
        // delete t2;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: The lexical scope of a variable has no influence on what happens when it is destroyed.

Comment: Use smart pointers if you really need pointers. Don't use pointers if you don't need them.

Comment: Also, if no exception is thrown, you have to delete the pointers as well.

Comment: Your first sentence implies that the local declarations cause a leak, and your second sentence claims that Valgrind says that they don't. Are both sentences true?

Comment: MFnx  This is just testing stuff. Obviously smart pointers is the way to go. however my question really is: Why isn't Valgrind detecting the leak when these pointers are declared outside main? If I comment out the pointers declared in main and uncomment the ones declared globally Valgrind is happy and not detecting leaks

Comment: I suppose Valgrind detected them, but they are in "still reachable" category.

Comment: Thank you @Yksisarvinen. Indeed! Tried exporting 'still reachable', and it correctly detects them. Cheers

Answer (score 2):

Declaring the variable global will make the pointer variable global, *not* what the pointer points to (which is *already* global as it is located on the heap).

Therefore, your current implementation also has a leak.

Local variables get destroyed when out of scope, but what they point to is not automatically out. Suggestion: forget completety `new` and `delete` operators and use STL or smart pointers.

Edit: You are asking why valgrind does not detect it, this is a different question than the original (I edited to add a tag).

Comment: As I said above, the obvious way to go is smart pointers. However, I am just testing stuff and run onto this, so I thought I 'd ask why isn't valgrind detecting the leak

Comment: That is something I don't know, but it seems to easy to detect so you may have a problem in valgrind setup. You didn't ask why valgrind doesn't detect it, you asked if it leaks.

Comment: Michael Chourdakis thank you for your reply. I will investigate.

Answer (score 1):

Right now you're always leaking memory, regardless if you're declaring pointers in main or globally.

Whenever you use `new` in your code, you need to use a `delete` or `delete[]`.

In modern C++, using `new` is considered a bad practice, you should be using `std::vector`, if you want an array, or `std::unique_ptr` if you're managing a pointer to an object.

Comment: Once more, the point is not the fact that we can now use smart pointers. Everyone is away of this. The point is why valgrind isn't detecting the leak

Answer (score 0):

As was mentioned already in other answers, the allocated object's destructor will not be called in both variants of your program, the scope and lifetime of the pointers do not influence what happens to the pointees, but you showed that already by printing in the destructor.

Valgrind will report this slightly differently however.

I ran the with a shorter array of 2 elements to reduce the amount of output.

The heap summary, which tells you what data remains on the heap at the end of the run, is the same for both programs:

```
==397== HEAP SUMMARY:
==397==     in use at exit: 12 bytes in 3 blocks
==397==   total heap usage: 6 allocs, 3 frees, 76,944 bytes allocated
```

That means both programs never deallocated the objects.

Valgrind does however make a difference between "definitely lost" allocations, with no reference to the memory blocks remaining in any variable and "still reachable" allocations, where a reference remains.

The leak summary with local pointers

```
==397== LEAK SUMMARY:
==397==    definitely lost: 12 bytes in 3 blocks
==397==    indirectly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==397==      possibly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==397==    still reachable: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==397==         suppressed: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
```

The leak summary with global pointers

```
==385== LEAK SUMMARY:
==385==    definitely lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==385==    indirectly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==385==      possibly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==385==    still reachable: 12 bytes in 3 blocks
==385==                       of which reachable via heuristic:
==385==                         length64           : 10 bytes in 1 blocks
```

If the pointers are local, valgrind can be sure that no reference remains, because after main returns, the stack locations are no longer valid.

If the pointers are global, they remain valid and could thus still be used or deallocated.

**Why does valgrind make this distinction?**

Especially in historic C programs it may be considered legitimate to allocate some memory once and use it throughout the execution, without bothering to later free the memory. The operating system will clean up the whole virtual memory space of the program anyway once the program exits. So while this could be a bug, it could also be intentional.
If you are interested in such leaks, valgrind itself tells you how it must be called to see them:

```
==405== Reachable blocks (those to which a pointer was found) are not shown. 
==405== To see them, rerun with: --leak-check=full --show-leak-kinds=all
```

"Definitely lost" memory is always suspicious, however, and that is why valgrind distinguished the cases. The value of a tool like valgrind lies in its precision. It is not sufficient to report many actual errors, in order to be useful it must also strive to produce a low number of false positives, otherwise looking at the reports would too often be a waste of developer time.

In modern C++, there are not many excuses for leaking memory, as `std::unique_ptr` should be the way to allocate dynamic objects. `std::vector` should be used for dynamic arrays and local objects used wherever possible as the compiler never forgets a deallocation. Even for singletons, the noise in the output of tools like valgrind and address sanitizer usually outweighs the usually minuscule benefits of saving one destructor call or deallocation.

Comment: Brilliant answer @PaulR. In fact, this is what I am looking at now in the valgrind manual. Thanks again for your though reply